# MongoDB LINQ select array elements with specific conditions

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, aggregation-framework

This is my MongoDB Data structure:

```
public class Part : ICloneable
    {
        string _id;
        ObservableCollection<DataElement> PartData;
        ObservableCollection<DataElement> SensorData;
    }
    public class DataElement: ICloneable
    {
        string description;
        string[] values;
    }
```

Using Linq I want to read all Parts `$projected`/reduced on the elements of SensorData, PartData and ResultData with a specific description.

Example:

```
Part{
_id: id1,
PartData[
    {description: "des1", values: "val1"},
    {description: "des2", values: "val2"}
],
SensorData[
    {description: "des3", values: "val5"},
    {description: "des4", values: "val2"},
    {description: "des5", values: "val2"}
]}
```

should be projected/reduced on all elements having the description "des2", "des4" and "des5", so that the data read looks like

```
Part{
_id: id1,
PartData[
    {description: "des2", values: "val2"}
],
SensorData[
    {description: "des4", values: "val2"},
    {description: "des5", values: "val2"}
]}
```

Each description is unique, but not every Part contains all descriptions.

Is there an easy solution for doing this without any $unwind/SelectMany? Something like

```
Select(p => p.PartData[] where p.PartData.Description == specifiedDescription),
p => p.SensorData[] where p.SensorData.Description == specifiedDescription))
```

but including the complete array element, while excluding the others and for PartData and SensorData?

Edit:
After the answer by Veeram I tried to implement the following:

```
parts = db.GetCollection<Part>("Part");        
var pipeline = parts.Aggregate()
.Project(p => new
{  PartData = p.PartData.Where(d => d.Description == specifiedDescription),
  SensorData = p.SensorData.Where(s => s.Description == specifiedDescription)
 }) ;
 var query = pipeline.ToEnumerable().AsQueryable();
 var returnParts = new ObservableCollection<Part>(query);
```

but this causes `pipeline` to be an anonymous `IAggregateFluent<'a>` instead of an `IAggregateFluent<Part>`, which makes `query` to be an anonymous `IQueryable<'a`> and therefore leading to the compile error "cannot convert from anonymous `IQueryable<'a`> to `IQueryable<Part>`" at the insertion of `query` as argument for the constructor of `ObservableCollection<Part>()`.

Without the `$select` the variables aren't anonymous anymore, but of class `<Part>` and the compile error doesn't occur. Obviously the `$select` changes the class of the aggregation.

How is it possible to solve this error? My idea would be to make the `$project` without generating a new class, but rather resetting some fields of the current class `<Part>`, but how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$filter` operator in `$project` stage with aggregation pipeline.

```
var pipeline = 
      collection.
            Aggregate()
              .Project(
                 p => new {
                  PartData= p.PartData.Where(d => d.Description == specifiedDescription),
                  SensorData= p.SensorData.Where(s=> s.Description == specifiedDescription)
            }
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was what I searched for!
Unfortunately there is this problem implementing it (see edited Question) do you know how to solve it?